# A question about reputation loss while downvoting

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, reputation

I have observed that these days if any user downvotes a question then they don't loose any points.

From [this link](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) from the Help page we find the following regarding when we loose reputation points:

> **You lose reputation when**:
>
> - your question is voted down: −2
> - your answer is voted down: −2
> - you vote down an answer: −1
> - you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
> - one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100
>
> All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never
> drop below 1. Accepting your own answer does not increase your
> reputation. Deleted posts do not affect reputation, for voters,
> authors or anyone else involved, in most cases. If a user reverses a
> vote, the corresponding reputation loss or gain will be reversed as
> well. Vote reversal as a result of voting fraud will also return lost
> or gained reputation.

So, as one can see, one does not loose any points when they are downvoting a question (they do if downvoting an answer). But if I'm not wrong the rule was not the same just may be a few years back. Am I right or wrong?

I think the rule was that you will loose 1 point as well even when you have downvoted a question provided your own reputation is less than a particular number (may be 500 or 1000 or may be even 5000 I don't remember exactly).

Is the rule really used to be like this before or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downvotes to questions used to cost 1 reputation (for the person voting down), just like answers. This has been changed, but that was a *long* time ago, May 2011 to be precise. See [Should downvotes on questions be “free”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90927/295232) on Meta Stack Exchage.

Comment: Oh but I thought I encountered this old rule around 2017 but looks like I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Rickross I have been using SE since 2014 and one doesn't lose reputation for downvoting questions. You may see more than [5 years old help center page](https://web.archive.org/web/20151015213107/http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Okay @Pandya I can't remember now how I got this idea.

Comment: @Pandya I still loose 1 point whenever I downvote a post...from reputation history, i could find few instances from Sep-2020..